# How to sort array using json key value using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I need one help.I want to some array value in descending order using PHP. I am explaining my code below.

i am getting the below output of this line `print_r($data);`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => cey0nsy1q,
            [pro_data_id] => 65
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [order_id] => yicldg6qn,
            [pro_data_id] => 65
        )
  [2] => Array
       (
         [order_id] => i562izwtc,
          [pro_data_id] => 92
       )
  [3] => Array
       (
         [order_id] => i662iuwti,
          [pro_data_id] => 93
       )
  [4] => Array
       (
          [order_id] => dg1usappz
          [pro_data_id] => 76
       )
)
```

From the above output i need to sort all value according to `pro_data_id` in descending order(`i.e-93,92,76,65,65.....`).Please help me.

Comment: @sougata  you can provide that duplicate link to help the questioner.

Comment: It is already showing